# Installing “platformio-ide-terminal@2.10.0” failed

Tags: atom-editor

This morning when I tried opening up the terminal in atom-editor from the package **platformio-ide-terminal** it was just blank. I uninstalled the package and when I tried to reinstall it the following failure message was shown:

```
Installing “platformio-ide-terminal@2.10.0” failed.Hide output…

> node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch@0.9.0-beta21.legacy install C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020914-9448-8l0dac.72tzp\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch
> prebuild-install || node scripts/install.js


C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020914-9448-8l0dac.72tzp\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.52.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.52.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild ) 

prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=6.1.12 runtime=electron arch=x64 libc= platform=win32)
gyp ERR! find VS 
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.6.30128.74) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "G:\VisualStudio"
gyp ERR! find VS - "Visual Studio C++ core features" missing
gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2013
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! node -v v12.4.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020914-9448-8l0dac.72tzp\package.json'
npm WARN apm-install-dir-2020914-9448-8l0dac.72tzp No description
npm WARN apm-install-dir-2020914-9448-8l0dac.72tzp No repository field.
npm WARN apm-install-dir-2020914-9448-8l0dac.72tzp No README data
npm WARN apm-install-dir-2020914-9448-8l0dac.72tzp No license field.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\.atom\.apm\_logs\2020-10-14T02_21_59_681Z-debug.log
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Install Microsoft Visual [Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) with "Desktop development with [C++](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/cplusplus/)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the link below to install Visual Studio Code :-

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools

It worked for me.